# why chars in the Set are rearranged?

Tags: python-3.x

I am a Java programmer and learning Python3. I found this example on Join.

```
set2 = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}
b = ''
print('Vowel characters are:', b.join(set2))
```

While I understand Join but why are the chars always in a different order, is it because {} is unordered?

I was expecting same order...